Is it advisable to contact faculty members at U.S. universities prior to submitting a PhD application?
In Iran, my home country, it's common practice for students applying to PhD programs to strongly emphasize the importance of emailing potential PhD supervisors before submitting their applications. However, after researching many universities across the U.S., I haven't found much instruction on this approach. Instead, most universities simply advise applicants to upload their documents, pay the application fee, and let the university distribute the relevant materials  to the supervisors we indicate on the application form.
I have a master's degree in industrial engineering, and a friend of mine holds a master's in food industries. We are both unsure of the best approach. Should we continue sending emails to potential supervisors, even if we receive no response, and then send reminders? Or should we simply proceed with the application process without reaching out to faculty members?
The main reason we want to establish some level of connection with a supervisor before applying is the high application fees, which are a significant burden in Iran due to the high inflation rate. We want to ensure that our money is not wasted by securing some level of support from someone within the department.
Thank you for your advice and consideration.

Applications are typically handled by the college and admissions by a departmental committee. You do not apply to a specific faculty. You will typically be asked somewhere in the process (if not at least in your letter) to list who you are interested in working with and why. This is enough in terms of letting faculty know that you exist and may be available if admitted.
Some things to be aware of:

Because so many of your colleagues are doing the same thing, faculty get flooded with emails from Iran (Pakistan and India are also high, but much less so of the latter in recent years). I get about 10 per week from that demographic pool pre application deadline. At some point, it just becomes a nuisance, because frankly all I can do is direct you to apply to the program through the appropriate venue anyway.

Committing to Iranian students is mostly not worth it to a faculty member until they arrive on site. I have trained several Iranian students and they were excellent researchers and lovely people, but the nature of US/Iran relationships and the potential for protracted visa applications means Iranian students are not reliable for a specific start time. So I will not set aside a grant for a potential student from Iran because they may not show up until next cycle.

Be mindful that certain states have implemented or are discussing laws that may prevent hiring Iranian students altogether (among a few other countries including Russia, Cuba, North Korea, etc.). Do a quick Google before sending out emails.

Trying to secure some level of support by establishing a personal connection in a way is trying to game the system which should be merit based and decided by the committee. Faculty know you are doing that because of the sheer number of applicants from that demographic zone (see point 1).  This becomes even worse when one applicant is sending half the department the same email!
Having sat on admissions committees in the past, the only time faculty typically interject is when they have a direct recruit, either from someone they met at a conference/or while giving an invited lecture, or coming from a colleague's lab… or the rare time a faculty is in trouble while on tenure track and we need to help them get more bodies in the lab.



This very much depends on the program. In our PhD program, students must have a faculty member committed to working with them to be admitted to the program.

@MichaelMior sure there are exceptions and that is typically evident when you apply, i.e. you are asked if you have secured an advisor. The general system in the US is a centralized process, hence the general advice.

@R1NaNo Fair enough. FWIW, I'm in the US but did grad school in Canada where I had the same experience of needing an advisor first. But that's fair that my experience might not be the norm.

R1NaNo is correct.

For most purposes and in most fields, it isn't common or necessary to contact potential advisors. It is permitted, but it is unlikely to make any difference in your acceptance into the program or their willingness to take you on. (Caveat: unless you are a superstar in some way)
Even with a masters, which most applicants in most fields don't have, the admission is via a committee and students aren't (normally) hired by professors.
The more common thing is to get accepted, begin your studies, and then meet with a few professors to get a sense of whether it would be mutually beneficial.
In any case, in most fields, one needs to pass comprehensive exams before becoming officially a candidate for the doctorate. This might involve coursework or not, depending on your masters, but the exams cover advanced material in the field and can be quite difficult.
You might ask a university to waive (or reduce) application fees but it wouldn't be the professor who handles that. An Office of Graduate Studies (or similar) might have information. And, an individual professor might not know how the committee might evaluate your application unless they have been on admissions committees. You would get an idea, perhaps, but no guarantees. Competition for limited slots can be very high.
It is common for professors to trash such messages or to simply reply "make a formal application and we can talk later". Follow up mails, when you don't get a reply in a couple of weeks are not going to help. If one of your professors sends an email on your behalf it might be more likely to be answered.
There are a few fields and a few places where students are hired by labs, but that isn't the norm in the US, unlike, say, Germany.
See the answer for the US to the canonical question on admissions for more information. And note the importance of reference letters.

I would be curious to see any data on whether "most fields" don't require contacting an advisor. I totally agree it differs by field, but I'm not sure about the frequency.

There are two main systems of PhD admissions around the world: (1) the "centralized" system where admission is handled by the department and where students are admitted to the "PhD program" and must find an advisor afterwards, and (2) the "decentralized" system where students apply directly to research groups, professors make the decisions themselves, and admission to the department/university/PhD program is merely a formality.
For the most part, universities in the US follow the centralized system.
In cases where the admission system is indeed centralized, there is literally no reason to contact individual professors. (Indeed, sometimes professors will write on their website something like "if you want to work with me as a graduate student, apply to the program–do not contact me directly."  If that's the case: please respect that!)
However, it's often the case that particular PhD programs have elements of the "decentralized" system. The mechanisms vary, but for example professors may have some limited ability to directly hire PhD students (especially if they happen to sit on the admissions committee) or they might be able to influence the admissions committee in some way. The extent to which this exists depends a lot on the field and the university.  In my field of physics, admission to theory groups is usually fully centralized but admission to experimental groups is sometimes partially decentralized.  It's often hard to find out how it works at a particular university, especially if you don't know anyone there and don't have the opportunity to visit, and since often times the admission system is "officially" centralized but has unofficial decentralized elements. One idea for you is to "cold-email" current PhD students at your university of interest. This may be more helpful than asking professors since: (1) students have more free time and often are more willing to help fellow students, and (2) students don't have to be as "politically-correct" as professors, and can tell you the important "unofficial" info.
Finally, it's worth mentioning that: if you genuinely have questions to ask or  ideas to share, rather than simply wanting to say "Hi, I'm interested in your research!" then go ahead and email the professor!  At best, it could lead to a fruitful conversation that may help you gain admission to the PhD program in the end, and at worst you would just be ignored.  Actually, even if all you have to say is the "hi I'm interested", you could just do it; it never hurts to try. (Unless, of course, they explicitly said not to: see my note above)

Thank you for your comment. I particularly like this part of your remark: One idea for you is to "cold-email" current PhD students at your university of interest. This may be more helpful than asking professors since: (1) students have more free time and often are more willing to help fellow students, and (2) students don't have to be as "politically-correct" as professors, and can tell you the important "unofficial" info.

@Afshin: I particularly like this part of your remark --- I too liked that part.

I do receive such emails, and in my case, they clearly show that I should not work with those students. Why? Because I am a staff scientist, and those students have simply grabbed the names of authors from academic journals and sent the same generic email to hundreds, if not thousands, of people. I work with PIs who may (if they have time and resources) engage with a student who cold-emails them, but only if the email is to the point (short), shows effort, and indicates that the student is genuinely passionate about their science, meaning they have read and understood the PI's papers. As for whether this approach helps you get into a PhD program, I have no idea. But whatever you do, avoid sending generic emails.
